# Error in playing the sound on a button click

Tags: android, audio

I have added two imageButton to my activity and on Clicking each one should play different sounds.
 But when I click on any Button the sound doesn't get play and the log shows error.

LOGCAT ERROR

```
09-30 15:19:07.436: D/dalvikvm(477): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 629 objects / 50520 bytes in 180ms
09-30 15:19:10.226: E/MediaPlayer(477): start called in state 1
09-30 15:19:15.276: E/MediaPlayer(477): start called in state 1
```

Here is the piece of code which I wrote,

```
import android.media.MediaPlayer;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


MediaPlayer mp;
ImageButton iV1,iV2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    iV1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.iV1);
    iV2 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.iV2);
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bud);
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.classic);

iV1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        mp = new MediaPlayer();
        mp.prepare();

        mp.start();

    }});

iV2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        mp = new MediaPlayer(); 
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();

    }});

    }
}
```

Please help me on this. Any help will be appreciated. I am New to this environment of Android.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a state machine issue, as the log clearly says :

```
09-30 15:19:10.226: E/MediaPlayer(477): start called in state 1
```

Refer : 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#StateDiagram

e.g., I dont see, where you are calling

```
MediaPlayer.setDataSource();
MediaPlayer.Prepare()
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems here. Firstly you're creating a new MediaPlayer object every time a button is pressed. You should remove these lines:

```
mp = new MediaPlayer();
mp1 = new MediaPlayer();
```

You already created the objects using the static create method.

Also as already mentioned, you need to call prepare before you call start:

```
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check [mediaplayer state diagream](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to get in trouble when using MediaPlayer for button-sounds, especially with more buttons. I have described a solution using SoundPool here: [How to Play sound when button is clicked in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753943/how-to-play-sound-when-button-is-clicked-in-android/20722454#20722454)