# How do I get a button to repeat a sound each time its clicked?

Tags: java, android

When I press a button it plays the sound fine but when I click it again nothing happens.
I want it to repeat the sound each time its clicked?  Any ideas??

Thanks for looking. :-)

package com.example.sherlock;

```
import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Conent extends Activity  {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.content);

        final MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1); 

        final MediaPlayer mp1 = new MediaPlayer();
        Button c = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button2); 


        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(mp.isPlaying())
                {  
                    mp.stop();
                    mp.reset();

                } 
                try {

                    AssetFileDescriptor afd;
                    afd = getAssets().openFd("s1.mp3");
                    mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());
                    mp.prepare();
                    mp.start();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



            }
        });

        c.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(mp1.isPlaying())
                {  
                    mp1.stop();
                    mp1.reset();
                } 
                try {

                    AssetFileDescriptor afd;
                    afd = getAssets().openFd("s2.mp3");
                    mp1.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());
                    mp1.prepare();
                    mp1.start();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



            }
        });





}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say that MediaPlayer "doesn't like" to be interupted while playing, what can be a case in your example if you click buttons while sounds are playing.

I think you can cut .reset() method from its place and paste it right before setDataSource in your try bloc:

```
mp.reset();
mp.setDataSource(MEDIA_PATH);
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```

It could possibly solve your problem, but have in mind that both reset() and prepare() are async methods so relying on MediaPlayer being responsive enough to handle them in your usecase is probably okay, but not a good practice.

Instead of using MediaPlayer, I would use SoundPool in your case. It seems that you aren't going to play long sounds (music or so), and your sounds can overlap. For this case, SoundPool is way way more reliable and faster.

I also found similar thread on stack overflow, hope it will help you a bit - [How to Play sound when button is clicked in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753943/how-to-play-sound-when-button-is-clicked-in-android), see Jan S answer.

Comment: Hey that worked.  I cut the .reset() and moved it to above setDataSource().   Thanks for your help. :-)

Comment: no problem, glad it helped. 
But try to refactor your code and use SoundPool :)

Answer (score 2):

```
   private SoundPool sp;
private int music;
sp= new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, 5);//the first param is times of play music                                at the same time
music = sp.load(this, R.raw.start, 1);//start is source music
        mButton01.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){   
            @Override   
           public void onClick(View v) {   
             sp.play(music, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);   
       }  
    }
```

maybe you can change your `*.mp3` to `*.ogg`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't reset your mp instead setup a mp.oncompletelistener and inside

```
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

//set the datasource again}
```

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is place these under your, if Button clicked event

```
  try{        
  mp.start();         
  }
    catch(Exception e){}
  }
```

and

```
  try{        
  mp1.start();         
  }
    catch(Exception e){}
  }
```