# Change default Android View.onClick sound

Tags: android, onclick, android-view

How can I change the default view.onClick sound? Is there any styleable where I can specify a path for a .mp3 (or other file type) in my raw folder to be played?

Thanks.

Comment: check out this link                                                  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753943/how-to-play-sound-when-button-is-clicked-in-android/20722454#20722454

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I came across was creating my onClick class who implements View.OnClickListener:

```
public static class MyViewOnClick implements View.OnClickListener {
    private MyViewOnClickListener listener;

    public MyViewOnClick(MyViewOnClickListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
               playSound(R.raw.btn_click);
               listener.onViewClicked(v);
    }
}

public interface MyViewOnClickListener {
    public void onViewClicked(View v);
}
```

in my activity:

```
myView.setOnClickListener(new MyViewOnClick(new MyViewOnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onViewClicked(View v) {
            ...
    }
}));
```

Comment: It's a helper method to play a sound

Answer (score 0):

you can play that sound by using `MediaPlayer` just add the sound file inside **/res/raw** and play it on the very first statement inside `onClickListener()` :

```
mediaPlayer.start();
```

you can initialize it inside `onCreate()`using

```
final MedialPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.mysound);
```

Comment: yes but that means that I'll have to repeat that .start() code inside all onClickListener(). I'm looking for a more generic solution. Is is possible?

Comment: I don't think there is another way. what you wish can only be achieved by altering sound preferences but that will change the sound for the whole device not just you app. so according to me this is the best you can do about if you dont want to poke around with settings.