# Want to play random sounds when button pressed android

Tags: android, eclipse

I am using the following code for playing a random sound when button is pressed, but it shows an error which i am unable to resolve. Could anybody please help:

```
 Button myButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

        final List<Integer> soundList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        soundList.add(R.raw.sound);
        soundList.add(R.raw.sound1);
        soundList.add(R.raw.sound2);
        soundList.add(R.raw.sound3);


       myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             playRandomSound();
        }

        private void playRandomSound() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int randomInt = (new Random().nextInt(soundList.size()));
            int sound = soundList.get(randomInt);
            MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, sound);
            mp.start();
        }
    });
```

ERROR: `The method create(Context, int) in the type MediaPlayer is not applicable for the arguments (new View.OnClickListener(){}, int)`

Comment: try passing `getactivity()` or `getapplicationContext()`

Comment: [check this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2754084/3767355)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The method create(Context, int) in the type MediaPlayer is not
>   applicable for the arguments (new View.OnClickListener(){}, int)

Pass `Activity` context as first parameter to `create`method as:

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(myButton.getContext(), sound);
```

Answer (score 0):

### You can use this.

```
final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.soho);
```

where "this" is the instance of your activity. Then in the onCLickListener of button call

```
mp.start();
```